# How do I install/generate all locales on Fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora, language, locale

`localectl list-locales` lists quite a selection of english language locales, but everything else is missing.

How do I install or generate all locales?

I tried installing all language packs with:

```
dnf langavailable | sed 's/.*\[/dnf -y langinstall /' | sed 's/\].*//' | sh
```

but that didn't help, so it seems language packs don't set up the locales for those languages?

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question here, as I got the answer via #fedora:

It turns out the image I was using (a droplet on Digital Ocean) has the following setting in `/etc/rpm/macros.image-language-conf`:

```
%_install_langs C:en:en_US:en_US.UTF-8
```

Changing that to all:

```
%_install_langs all
```

And then reinstalling glibc fixed it for me:

```
sudo dnf reinstall glibc-common
```

Comment: Tried adding `:fi_FI:fi_FI.UTF-8` to the end of the list but that didn't work. Instead adding `fi_FI` before the `en_US.UTF-8` entry worked.. Wonder if the installer fails to parse the .UTF-8 correcty..